# Issue using Selenium grid with Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm setting up a Selenium Grid for remote automated testing, and can't seem to start a test on a Microsoft Edge node.

I set up my node on a test machine with this command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -port 5555 -role node -hub http://192.168.1.201:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=MicrosoftEdge, platform=WINDOWS, maxInstances=10"
```

And I try sending a simple test like this:

```
[SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Edge();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.201:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    [Test]
    public void UrlCheck()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://google.com";
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void EndTest()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

When I run the above on my test machine, I can see it open the Edge browser (so it's getting to the node fine), but it can't navigate to the URL.

In Visual Studio I get this error:

```
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I can't find much information on sending tests to an Edge node. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-Dwebdriver.edge.driver= "C:\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" instead of Dwebdriver.ie.driver`